# How to populate a repository with a copy of an old svn repository

Tags: svn

I configured long time ago a backup script for one of my svn repository. Such a noob i was, i didn't used 'svnadmin dump' but just made an archive of my repository folder.

I don't have access to the old server anymore thus the only thing i have a archives of the old repository folder.

is there a way to import those archive into my new server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the problem?
You just have to decompress the repository folder and copy it to the appropriate folder

Comment: i've read somewhere that i need to use the same version of the svnserver for this to work. is this true?